# Run as Javascript inlines polymer-element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

My "Run as Javascript" works, but it inlines all custom elements. In the dart version the custom elements are in a separate file and since I eventually want to use these elements for integration purposes I think it would be much more cleaner to keep it like that.

Is there a way to tell pub build/"Run as Javascript" to keep the custom element definition(s) separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse built Polymer elements anyway so that wouldn't make sense.

You have to reuse the Dart code and build the resulting application to JS.

In-lining makes sense because the browser gets the entire application in one (or fewer) request instead of multiple calls fore each element.

Comment: Thanks, i did not think about the performance penalty. However i still think having the definition in a separate file feels more (web) component like and is easier for the integrating party to adjust their webpage. Shouldn't this be left as a choice/option for the developer?

Comment: When you write the definition in a separate file you have it in a separate file. You and other users of the component develop with this code. Dart2JS is ONLY for deployment this has nothing to do with development. That said it is possible to make parts of the app loaded lazy (on Demand) but that is not very mature yet and I haven't used it myself yet.